# WixBundleOriginalSource Alternative

Tags: path, directory, wix, bundle, built-in

I need to get the path of the .exe installer or its folder's path.  We were using WixBundleOriginalSource, but that variable does not change if another install is run - it always refers to the original source (as you would expect).  So subsequent installations always expect to use the original folder.

Is there any way to refer to the *current* installer's directory?